# Understanding Debian dpkg package version numbers

Tags: debian, dpkg

When I type `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg`, I get a list of installed packages and their versions:

```
ii  xserver-xorg               1:7.7+3~deb7u1
ii  xserver-xorg-core          2:1.12.4-6
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev   1:2.7.0-1+b1
ii  xserver-xorg-input-kbd     1:1.6.1-1+b1
ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse   1:1.7.2-3
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon  1:6.14.4-8
```

I am wondering what the number in front of the colon means, i.e. the number `2` in `2:1.12.4-6`

Comment: This is a less general rehash of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114708/5132 , which covers everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [version numbers in Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) are of the form

```
[epoch:]upstream_version[-debian_revision]
```

where

- `epoch` is a single (generally small) unsigned integer, which is included to allow mistakes in the version numbers of older versions of a package. If omitted, the `epoch` is assumed to be zero.
- `upstream_version`  is usually the version number of the original source package from which the .deb file has been made. It is usually kept the same as the format used for the upstream source.
- `debian_revision` specifies the version of the Debian package based on the upstream version. It is optional and is omitted in cases where a piece of software was written specifically to be a Debian package.

Answer (score 1):

The `2` is the *epoch*.

More fully, from [`man deb-version`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/deb-version.5.html):

```
[epoch:]upstream-version[-debian-revision]
```

`epoch`

```
This is a single (generally small) unsigned integer.  It may be omitted,  in  which
case  zero  is assumed.  If it is omitted then the upstream-version may not contain
any colons.

It is provided to allow mistakes in the version numbers  of  older  versions  of  a
package,  and  also  a  package's  previous  version  numbering schemes, to be left
behind.
```

`upstream-version`

```
This is the main part of the version number.  It is usually the version  number  of
the  original  ("upstream") package from which the .deb file has been made, if this
is applicable.  Usually this will be in the same format as that  specified  by  the
upstream  author(s); however, it may need to be reformatted to fit into the package
management system's format and comparison scheme.

The comparison behavior of the  package  management  system  with  respect  to  the
upstream-version  is  described  below. The upstream-version portion of the version
number is mandatory.

The  upstream-version  may  contain  only  alphanumerics  ("A-Za-z0-9")   and   the
characters  . + - : ~ (full stop, plus, hyphen, colon, tilde) and should start with
a digit.  If there is no debian-revision then hyphens are not allowed; if there  is
no epoch then colons are not allowed.
```

`debian-revision`

```
This  part  of the version number specifies the version of the Debian package based
on the upstream version.  It may contain only alphanumerics and the characters +  .
~  (plus, full stop, tilde) and is compared in the same way as the upstream-version
is.

It is optional; if it isn't present then the upstream-version  may  not  contain  a
hyphen.   This  format  represents  the  case where a piece of software was written
specifically to be turned  into  a  Debian  package,  and  so  there  is  only  one
"debianisation" of it and therefore no revision indication is required.

It  is  conventional  to  restart  the  debian-revision  at  '1' each time time the
upstream-version is increased.

Dpkg will break the version number apart at the last hyphen in the string (if there
is  one)  to  determine  the upstream-version and debian-revision. The absence of a
debian-revision compares earlier than the  presence  of  one  (but  note  that  the
debian-revision is the least significant part of the version number).
```