# Package versioning in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

Linux Mint shows package versions like on the provided screenshot. So I'm interesting what  `-1ubuntu.1.5`  part means? Because Git reports its version as `2.34.1` before updating and after updating like nothing has changed at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [What does the version string from dpkg/aptitude/apt-show-versions mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622325/86440) and [understanding Debian dpkg package version numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96599/86440) for explanations of the versioning used in Debian packages (of which this is a special case).

The `-1ubuntu1.4` and `-1ubuntu1.5` suffixes are packaging-specific. The upstream version, 2.34.1, hasn’t changed, as you’ve noticed. The `ubuntu` part indicates that this is a Ubuntu-specific version of the package, on top of a Debian package (version 1:2.34.1-1).

You can see details of the changes [in the package changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.5): this is a security update, merging a number of security fixes on top of 2.34.1. So while the upstream version hasn’t changed, this is really a slightly newer version of git; it doesn’t correspond to a released upstream version of git, but it includes security fixes from later releases.